# Centripetal force equation doubt

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, acceleration, rotational-kinematics

> In a centrifuge, $a_c$ should be constant. If $m$ increases, the $r$ will increase in order to maintain a constant $a_c$.

Constant centrieptal acceleration is given by
$a_c={ v^2 \over r}$

and $a_c = \omega^2 * r$

But the conflict between these two equations arises when we increase $r$.
In the first equation - if we increase $r$, $v$ should increase so that $a_c$ remains constant.
But in the second equation - since $\omega$ is constant in a centrifuge, if we increase $r$ then $a_c$ is no longer constant.

I dont understand how this is happening and would appreciate any help.I have also looked at other similar questions on this site but they do not answer to this conflict. This is not a duplicate.

Also, does anyone know how to mathematically show that radius increases when mass increases?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which variables of motion are kept constant in a centrifuge?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/660443/)

Comment: no. It states what is constant. but it doesnt address the  conflict between the two equations.

Comment: This should help you hopefully, I had a very similar confusion. [link](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/659352/)

Comment: It may be a confusion about what "constant" means here. The acceleration is constant in time, once the maximum velocity is achieved. But the acceleration depends on the distance from the center.

Comment: What does 'm' mean(in the blockquote)?

Comment: *"In a centrifuge, $a_c$ should be constant"*. Whose $a_c$?

Comment: Where is the quote from?

Comment: ac is that of the test tube

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The misconception lies on for what you define $a_c$. *Imagine* that you put two balls with mass $M$ and $m$ in the centrifuge ($M\gt m$). When the centrifuge reaches constant angular velocity $\omega$, let's say those balls are respectively $R$ and $r$ distance away from the centre of rotation. From the observation we know that $R\gt r$.* Now let's calculate the centripetal acceleration of two masses. $$M\Rightarrow a_c=R\omega^2$$ $$m\Rightarrow a_c=r\omega^2$$ This yields, centripetal acceleration of $M$ is greater than that of $m$. Which means that the sentence

> In a centrifuge, $a_c$ should be constant

makes no sense.

---

*Physics concepts are based on observations. Not observations are built by physics concepts.

Answer (score 3):

Both the equations are equivalent. By definition of angular velocity,
$$\omega=v/r$$

You substitute this in $m \omega^2 r$ to get $m v^2/r$.

NOTE THAT $\omega$ is not constant if you change radius, as you claim!

---

And for the mass to radius relation, its straight forward. Take,
$$F_c = m v^2 /r$$ and ask what you get if you keep $F_c$ constant while increasing the radius.

Answer (score 3):

If $a_c$ really means the magnitude of centripetal acceleration and $m$ means mass then the sentence

> If $m$ increases, the $r$ will increase in order to maintain a constant $a_c$.

cannot be correct, since neither expression for $a_c$ involves $m$ at all; $a_c$ is independent of $m$.

If $\omega$ were changing over time then $r$ could also change to maintain a constant $a_c$. But in a centrifuge (in its steady state) the angular speed $\omega$ is constant, so $a_c$ is also constant for a given value of $r$. If $r$ changes then $a_c \propto r$.

Comment: are all the particles, regardless of mass, rotating in the centrifuge at the same centripetal acceleration?

Comment: @WinnieThePooh Only if they are all at the same radius $r$ - which rather defeats the purpose of a centrifuge. If different particles have different values of $r$ then $a_c \propto r$.

Comment: is there a mathematical representation of the equal and opposite force for centripetal force? The equal and opposite force can't possibly  be radially outwards (and therefore not really opposite) because...well...I thought centrifugal force is just inertia and tangential velocity. Or maybe I am completely wrong.

Comment: @WinnieThePooh "equal and opposite" means just what it says - equal in magnitude and opposite in direction. The centrifuge exerts a centripetal force on each tube that it is spinning, and so each tube exerts an equal and opposite force on the centrifuge. The force exerted by each tube on the centrifuge will be radially outwards. It is normal to load a centrifuge with pairs of tubes opposite one another so that the forces on the centrifuge from different tubes approximately balance out.

Comment: oh. i see. thank you

Comment: sorry . i have another stupid question. If mass increases, then centrifugal force increases and  the centripetal force increase as well. From the both the mass perspective and centrifuge perspective, the corresponding centripetal force in each frame is increasing and are equal. so which way should the increasing mass really go?

Comment: @WinnieThePooh Comments are not intended for extended discussions. If you have more questions then you need to start with a new post.

Answer (score 1):

I do not see what is the conflict here .

If you increase the radius while also increasing the velocity appropriately, then  acceleration will stay constant.

But if you increase the radius, while keeping the angular velocity constant, then acceleration will increase.

What is the conflict in that ?